# What is the best way to send a GET request to the server in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

What is the best way to send a GET request to the server in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: when you say vanilla JS, do you mean without using any package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Comment: What does this have to do with `python-requests`? It's also very different for browser js and the `node.js` tag you also used. Also, what criteria do you use for "best way"?

Answer (score 11):

In vanilla javascript, you can use [the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Comment: or more briefly 
`(await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')).json()`

Comment: Beware that `response.json()` here only returns a `Promise`, not the parsed response payload, hence the need for the additional `.then(myJson) => ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can do a redirection to do a synchronous GET request:

```
var url = 'http://domain/path/?var1=&var2=';

window.location = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (XHR) Object.

Code example:

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='/test';
http.open("GET", url);
http.send();

http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  console.log('done')
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, the raw XHR API is outdated. The modern way, which is more elegant and also supports Promises out of the box, is to use fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", THE_URL, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

Comment: While this is correct, the raw XHR API is outdated. The modern way, which is more elegant and also supports Promises out of the box, is to use fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Fetch

```js
function request() {
            fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.json())
                })
                .then(function(myJson) {
                    console.log(myJson);
                });
        }

        request()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if we can claim here a "best way", 
but you can use

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

or if you want to use a library

[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Answer (score -1):

if you get installt PHP  you can use the get_file_content var

```
 <html>
<script>
var date= "<?php 
echo(file_get_contents('https://apizmanim.com/twilio/zipapi.php?11211?2021/05/14')?>";
document.write(date);
</script>
</html>
```